# Functions to Round up and Round down fractions with precision in PHP, any better way to do it?

Tags: php, function, math

I found this code on php.net which works for me for the round_up part..

```
function round_up($value, $precision = 0) { 
 if (!empty($value)) {
 $sign = (0 <= $value) ? +1 : -1; 
 $amt = explode('.', $value); 
 $precision = (int) $precision; 
 if (strlen($amt[1]) > $precision) { 
     $next = (int) substr($amt[1], $precision); 
     $amt[1] = (float) (('.'.substr($amt[1], 0, $precision)) * $sign); 
     if (0 != $next) { 
         if (+1 == $sign) { 
             $amt[1] = $amt[1] + (float) (('.'.str_repeat('0', $precision - 1).'1') * $sign); 
         } 
     } 
 } 
 else { 
     $amt[1] = (float) (('.'.$amt[1]) * $sign); 
 } 
 return $amt[0] + $amt[1]; 
 }
 else {echo 'error';} 
 }
```

Added a couple minus's.. to get this one...

```
function round_down($value, $precision = 0) { 
 if (!empty($value))  {
 $sign = (0 <= $value) ? +1 : -1; 
 $amt = explode('.', $value); 
 $precision = (int) $precision; 
 if (strlen($amt[1]) > $precision) { 
     $next = (int) substr($amt[1], $precision); 
     $amt[1] = (float) (('.'.substr($amt[1], 0, $precision)) * $sign); 
     if (0 != $next) { 
         if (-1 == $sign) { 
             $amt[1] = $amt[1] - (float) (('.'.str_repeat('0', $precision - 1).'1') * $sign); 
         } 
     } 
 } 
 else { 
     $amt[1] = (float) (('.'.$amt[1]) * $sign); 
 } 
 return $amt[0] + $amt[1]; 
 }
 else {echo 'error';}
 }
```

Is there any better way to do it? (I only require it for positive decimals) Currently for the most part it works without much glitches..

```
$azd = 0.0130; 

$azd1 = number_format(round_up($azd,2),4);
$azd2 = number_format(round_down($azd,2),4);
$azd3 = number_format(round_up($azd,1),4);
$azd4 = number_format(round_down($azd,1),4);

echo 'Round_up = '.$azd1.'<br>'; // 0.0200
echo 'Round_down = '.$azd2.'<br>'; // 0.0100
echo 'Round_up = '.$azd3.'<br>';    // 0.1000
echo 'Round_down = '.$azd4.'<br>';  // 0.0000
```

Comment: Wont the round() with extra options work well?
http://php.net/manual/en/function.round.php

Comment: Rounding `0.0130` gives `0.1`? What kind of math are you doing?

Comment: @NullUserException He is rounding the values up to a certain precision of 1 decimal.

Comment: @JohnCartwright In which case `0.0130` should give you `0.0`

Comment: @NullUserException Your assuming that the rounding up is based on values of 5 or higher. This is not the case as it will blindly round any value to the given precision. 0.01 becomes 0.1 with a precision of 1.

Comment: @JohnCartwright That's not how rounding works. 0.01 "rounding" to anything but 0.0 is meaningless (with precision = 1).

Comment: @NullUserException Correct, but his question is how to accomplish his requirements more efficiently (which is not normal rounding).

Comment: @NullUserExceptionఠ_ఠ  - not so meaningless where I use the functions..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
function round_up($value, $precision=0) {
    $power = pow(10,$precision);
    return ceil($value*$power)/$power;
}
function round_down($value, $precision=0) {
    $power = pow(10,$precision);
    return floor($value*$power)/$power;
}
```

Comment: Ahh you beat me to it! Voted up =]

Answer (score 1):

```
function round_up($float,$mod) {
    return ceil($float * pow(10,$mod)) / pow(10,$mod);
}
function round_down($float,$mod=0) {
    return floor($float * pow(10,$mod)) / pow(10,$mod);
}
```

Comment: Essentially identical to Kolink's answer, except you replaced their `$power` variable with the entire expression.

Comment: If you look at my comment on his post, he answered as I was submitting, and it's not a copy, it's just the best way to do it.

Comment: I didn't say it was a copy, just that it's the same answer.

Answer (score 0):

The above answers not working for me, I got these from [PHP Ceil and Floor to the nearest 100 with rounding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32203359/php-ceil-and-floor-to-the-nearest-100-with-rounding)

```
function ceiling($number, $significance) {
   if ($significance != null) {
      return (is_numeric($number) && is_numeric($significance) ) ? (ceil($number / $significance) * $significance) : $number;
   } else {
      return $number;
   }
}

function flooring($number, $significance) {
   if ($significance != null) {
      return (is_numeric($number) && is_numeric($significance) ) ? (floor($number / $significance) * $significance) : $number;
   } else {
      return $number;
   }
}
```