# What is the equivalent of Excel's FLOOR(number,significance) in PHP?

Tags: php

I am looking to floor/round a number with a certain significance.

For example 2499 => 2400. This can be achieved in excel using `=FLOOR(2499, 100)`

What is the equivalent function for this in PHP? Or is there a library / custom function that solves this problem?

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.round.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this approach:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/7491541/2731161

So:

```
round_down('2499',-2); #results in 2400
```

Note the precision value. You'll need the round_down function from the posted answer.

Comment: bang on. effective function.

Answer (score 0):

it's floor();

(would you believe?) there's no precision setting.. this function is from the [PHP manual page](http://php.net/manual/en/function.floor.php) - purports to add decimal places though I've not tested it.

Otherwise you could multiply by 100 (if you want 2 dps), use floor(), then divide by 100 to get the result.

```
Floor decimal numbers with precision:

function floor_dec($number,$precision,$separator){
$numberpart=explode($separator,$number);
$numberpart[1]=substr_replace($numberpart[1],$separator,$precision,0);
if($numberpart[0]>=0)
{$numberpart[1]=floor($numberpart[1]);}
else
{$numberpart[1]=ceil($numberpart[1]);}

 $ceil_number= array($numberpart[0],$numberpart[1]);
return implode($separator,$ceil_number);
}

echo floor_dec(1.125,2,"."); //1.12
echo floor_dec(-1.3436,3,"."); //-1.344
echo floor_dec(102938.1,4,"."); //102938.1
```

Comment: Without trying this function out I would want to avoid string manipulation as an approach. Would be an inefficient approach. The approach in @user5923's answer works.

Comment: Yes I would too.. If you're always using the same rounding I'd not bother with a general function, it seems a waste. In your example you just have to divide by 100, use floor(), then x by 100 again to get your answer.